# SQL Server 7 Transaction Logs Issues

Tags: windows, database, sql-server, windows-server, transaction

Over the week my database server transaction log was full. With our app people could select from the database but could not update or insert into the database. In the past we have just truncated the transaction logs. After that, everything was back to normal.

This week I truncated the transaction logs, and shrink that database. Now we can select, update, and insert into the database. The only issue is when we do a big job, and to a lot on inserting or updating, we get the following error:

```
Database error: S1008:[Microsft][ODBC]Operation canceled
```

We never had this issue before, I am assuming the that is the same as a timeout error. Has anyone else had this issue before, or know how I resolve this?

Comment: It sounds like you should set the database recovery model to Simple as it doesn't sound like you're managing the transaction log with backups.

Answer (score 2):

Truncating transaction log is not the best option to maintain SQL Server. If your recovery plan doesn't need transaction log backup you can switch it to Simple. Take a look on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx), choose recovery model based on your needs